# Finding Sequence in Third Square

Tags: number-sequence

This particular puzzle is throwing me off for some reason, given that solutions I've tried for similar problems are not working.

**Problem**

Given that you have this square:

```
.14   .21
   .22
.17   .26
```

and this one:

```
.4    .3
   .0
.2    .1
```

What should replace the question mark in this one:

```
.0008    .007
       ?
.06      .1
```

**Working It Out**

I was trying variants of multiply the bottom right/left and then the top right/left and then vice versa. None of those normal patterns seem to work, or I missed an obvious one.

I recognize that the first table is a 3-4-5 pattern but I don't know if that matters. (Meaning, .14 to .17 is 3; .17 to .21 is 4; .21 to .26 is 5.) But that doesn't hold for the other squares, even as a general pattern.

If anyone has any ideas, I'm open to them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The middle term seems to be:

> 1 minus the sum of the other four terms

In the case of the first, this equates to:

> $1 - (.14 + .17 + .21 + .26) = 1 - .78 = .22$

In the case of the second, this equates to:

> $1 - (.4 + .3 + .2 + .1) = 1 - 1 = 0$

This leads us to our final result of:

> $1 - (.1 + .06 + .007 + .0008) = 1 - .1678 = .8322$

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this explanation. And I'm sad that I didn't pick up on this myself.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is

> bottom right plus bottom left minus top right. This would give 0.153 for the question mark.

It feels odd not to use the top left, but it works.

Comment: You know it's interesting that this happens to work in this particular circumstance with the numbers as provided. Huh.

Comment: It is interesting. I am sure that if there was one more sample, my answer would break.

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that each of the puzzles

> Adds up to 1

The first puzzle:

> $0.14 + 0.17 + 0.21 + 0.26 + 0.22 = 1$

And the second puzzle:

> $0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4 + 0.0 = 1$

Since the third puzzle is already:

> $0.0008 + 0.06 + 0.007 + 0.1 = 0.1678$

That would make the solution:

> $1 - 0.1678 = 0.8322$

<sub>I actually realised after joining that [Green already posted this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/54665/40446) but explained differently.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Alpha, in my mind I meant to use spoiler blocks but clearly not.

Comment: Haha, all good. I'm still getting used to formatting here too.